# Displaying notification in control panel

Tags: control-panel

Is there any js function that will display these notifications that appear on top of the screen? Flash messages use these notifications, but I don't want to use flash messages, I want to display notification without refreshing a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft's JS/UI framework "Garnish" is largely undocumented, but exploring the `Craft` object it exposes in the console, I found a few methods that might be useful:

```js
// Good for confirmations (blue banners):
Craft.cp.displayNotice('Your changes have been saved.');

// Good for errors (red banners):
Craft.cp.displayError('Uh oh, something bad happened!');

// Custom flash names (for anything else—requires custom CSS):
Craft.cp.displayNotification('custom-flash-key', 'Something very special happened!');
```

The last one, `displayNotification` is the abstract method, called by the first two. `custom-flash-key` gets added to the notification as a classname.

Comment: How could these be set from a module?

Comment: how to do this with craft 4?

Comment: @AugustineCalvino Generally speaking, flashes set from the back-end (i.e. a controller) should go through `Craft::$app->getSession()->setNotice($message)` and `->setError($message)`. Craft will automatically render those notifications for you when the page loads!

Comment: @tenshi This still applies to Craft 4. 4.2.0 introduced rich notifications, which means these JavaScript methods now support additional arguments—haven't had a chance to document this, yet, though!